# HTTP basic Auth and OAuth in combination

Tags: authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a client application that needs to authenticate specific request pattern via Basic Auth and rest else via OAuth. I am using @EnableOAuth2Sso to enable the Oauth.

I have autowired a secutiryConfig bean in my springBootApp like this

```
public class ClientApp {

   @Autowired 
   private SecurityConfig config;
}
```

and SecurityConfig is defined as

```
 @Component
 @EnableOAuth2Sso
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()     
  .anyRequest().authenticated();
 }
```

I need to have basic auth on pattern '/admin/** ' 
and OAuth on '/users/** '

Basic auth has to be using the jdbcAuthentication.
I can make Oauth or Basic Auth separately working for all patterns. But how to make them work simultaneously for this case.